# Some band/musician rebuses

Tags: rebus, knowledge, music

Here's a bunch of rebuses for you. Each represents a band or a musician. 
Hope you'll enjoy :)

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

4)

[image]

Comment: #2: In case of silence, break glass.

Comment: @Veskah but this is not a band (or is it?)

Comment: That's why it's a comment instead of an answer. Alternatively, wanna join my band? I have an idea for the name.

Comment: I think we need a new tag for "Don't bother if you're old".  I've never heard of any of these bands.  :)

Comment: @pugmonkey Each of these bands are 15+ years old (25 for the last one) :p. But that's maybe not the kind of music you listen to ;)

Comment: @Flying_whale  You're right - I looked up some info on the bands and it is definitely not my style.  But keep the rebuses coming - I enjoy them even if I'm a little lost on the answers.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing now since no answer was selected, and to put all answers in one place.

1)

> Mario Duplantier from the band Gojira/Godzilla

2)
From @Kant1:

> Stuck in the sound

3)

> Arcade Fire

4)
From @Riley:

> Electric Wizard. It's Harry Potter (a wizard) holding a resistor (an electronic component).

Comment: yep 1 and 3 are correct :)

Answer (score 5):

I think 4 might be

> **Electric Wizard**. It's Harry Potter (a wizard) holding a resistor (an electronic component).

Comment: yep yep that's it :) (+ the generator on his belly and the electric hazard sign in place of his scar ;) )

Comment: @Flying_whale Wow, didn't notice the scar. Pretty clever. I saw the G, but I thought it stood for Gryffindor or something :)

Answer (score 5):

for 2) I thought of

> Stuck in the sound

But it's probably not the right answer since I don't think this band in known outside of France

Comment: This is the right answer :). And I am French so maybe that's why I know it :p

Answer (score 2):

2) I don't know how well known this band is, but it fits the image too perfectly to ignore:

> [Music Jar](https://www.facebook.com/musicjarband/)?

Comment: Nope sorry, don't know that band and I have to say it fits well :)